# Does it ever make sense to maintain state within classes alongside state managed by context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am starting down the path of refactoring my react state management to utilize Context API.

I have setup a basic state manager and am passing context into a config file which goes into individual forms to avoid props drilling.

**State.js**

```js
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

**Architecture**
[image]

**Issue**

I feel like it will get confusing identifying where state for each component is coming from if I have state management within components and the context API, but one of the things I like about having state within each component is knowing which states belong to that component.

**Question**

Does it ever make sense to maintain state managed within components alongside the context API? Or should I eventually refactor all state to be managed by State.js

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me you should manage state at the component level as much as possible.  You need to be careful using the context api as you will re-render every component that is a consumer of the context whenever a single value in the context changes resulting in a poor performing app.  The documentation for the context api touches on this.  It is good for managing things like user authentication or managing themes colors and things that don't change a lot but not for rapidly changing values or complex stores.  So managing state in a form component for example where you are changing the state with every keystroke should be managed at the component level.

All that said the context api is great for managing a small store that does not have a high frequency.  But if you have a complex store connecting to a lot of components then you really shouldn't use the context api and you should really go for something like redux.  It's kind of a pain to setup but you don't get the constant re-rendering of every consumer component like you would with the context api.